# Run query on each SQL Server instance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The first query retrieves the list of installed instances:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @GetInstances TABLE
     ( Value nvarchar(100),
     InstanceNames nvarchar(100),
     Data nvarchar(100))
Insert into @GetInstances
EXECUTE xp_regread
     @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
     @key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server',
     @value_name = 'InstalledInstances'
Select 
     InstanceNames 
From 
     @GetInstances
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

The second query could be anything but for the sake of argument, this one will do; it retrieves the list of trace ids for each trace instance:

```
    select distinct 
         info.eventid 
    from 
         sys.traces as tr 
    cross apply sys.fn_trace_geteventinfo (tr.id) as info
```

So in summary, I want to feed the resultant instances from the first query into the second query so that I return all the values for all of the installed instances. There could be just one default instance but there could also be several.

Comment: You cannot use a variable for a database, table or a column name.  You would need to use dynamic queries.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use a Cursor.

Note: Cursors are kinda slow, and generally you want to keep them to a minimum.

Check out [this](http://stevestedman.com/2013/04/t-sql-a-simple-example-using-a-cursor/) link to learn about them in depth.

But to be short: they can let you loop over a result set and execute tsql per row

Your code:

```
declare @GetInstances table
     ( 
        Value nvarchar(100),
        InstanceNames nvarchar(100),
        Data nvarchar(100)
    )
insert into @GetInstances
exec xp_regread
     @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
     @key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server',
     @value_name = 'InstalledInstances'


declare @Cursor as cursor;
declare @Server varchar(50);

set @Cursor = cursor for
select 
     InstanceNames
from 
     @GetInstances

 
open @Cursor;
fetch next from @Cursor into @Server;
 
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
 print @Server
 fetch next from @Cursor into @Server;
END
 
close @Cursor;
deallocate @Cursor;
```

**edit:**

To use this server name to execute a proc, we need 2 things.

1. We need to make sure the server is setup as a linked server
2. We need to write a tiny bit of dynamic SQL (This is simple, don't worry)

#### Linked server

Linked servers are pretty simple in concept. Basically, they allow communication between severs via t-sql.

To setup a linked server, [Microsoft has documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560998.aspx), but basically, in ssms, right click `Server Objects > New > Linked Server` and then follow all the steps to setup a sql server linked server.

And then boom. You now have a linked server.

#### Dynamic sql

Dynamic sql is cool and useful, and can really help in situations like this.

Normally, how we would execute a stored procedure on a linked server is this:

```
exec [RemoteServer].DatabaseName.Schema.StoredProcedureName
```

but, in our case, we don't know what `[RemoteServer]` is at time of writing. So what we can do, is write some Dynamic sql. With dynamic sql, what we can do is execute a string of tsql on our db, so we can do something like

```
exec(@Server + '.DatabaseName.Schema.StoredProcedureName')
```

and it runs the proc on the remote server.

Comment: So where exactly does the query go that uses the instance values? If I put a query in where 'print @Server' is after the 'begin' command, it seems as if the result is coming from the first/default instance. It's repeated three times but the answer is always the same. For example. I installed SQL Server 2012 on a test box and also installed two extra instances. On the third instance I set it up as Windows authentication only but if I plug in:

        EXEC XP_LOGINCONFIG 'login mode' 

after the begin command, although I DO get three separate responses, they all show Mixed mode.

Comment: See my edit above, I think it goes into more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't see either of these examples working for my needs because I won't have the kinds of rights needed to create a linked server and secondly, I won't know ahead of time what the instances are called. I think what I'm going to have to do is use a batch language or PowerShell wrapper around the t-sql statement that pulls the instance names from the registry and then use a 'sqlcmd -S .\<instance>' kind of thing. I sincerely appreciate your help, however.